# How to filter one row, calculate range and find similar rows from it falling within that range in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

How to filter one row, calculate range and find similar rows from it falling within that range in a dictionary with id as key and id's falling in that range as values using multiprocessing?

Suppose I have a data frame:

```
id  val1   val2
1    10     20
2    9.5    19
3    100    200
4    9.3    19.2
5    96     196
6    99     198
7    103    202
8    140    280
```

For each id *i*, I will calculate:

```
upper_val1 = df[df.id==i].val1 * (1+0.1) 
lower_val1 = df[df.id==i].val1 * (1-0.1) 
upper_val2 = df[df.id==i].val2 * (1+0.1) 
lower_val2 = df[df.id==i].val2 * (1-0.1)
```

Subset df:

```
sub_df = df[(df.val1<=upper_val1)&df.val1>=lower_val1)&(df.val1<=upper_val2)&df.val1>=lower_val2)
```

For whichever id, val1 lies between this range, that will be put in the dictionary. For eg. the output of this df will be:

```
{1:[2,4], 2:[1,4], 4:[1,2], 3:[5,6,7], 5:[3,6,7], 6:[3,5,7], 7:[3,5,6]}
```

I have a data frame with millions of records and this step should be repeated for each row, so how it can be done using multiprocessing?

Comment: I was about to suggest self-merged, but then I saw millions of rows and I give up. You are looking at `10 ** 12` pair-wise comparison here.

Comment: If its possible to utilize a numpy array instead of pandas you may have a workaround. Cupy is basically numpy made for CUDA cores on a NVIDIA graphics card. I've seen orders of magnitude speed up in matrix math using this method as graphics cards can have hundreds or thousands of cores. It really depends on if the math can be performed on your CPU cache or requires more.

Comment: @Jake can you share an example code?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, we'll apply a function over the dataframe that computes the IDs where values lie in a range of the dataframe's rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
         {'id': 1, 'val1': 10.0, 'val2': 20.0},
         {'id': 2, 'val1': 9.5, 'val2': 19.0},
         {'id': 3, 'val1': 100.0, 'val2': 200.0},
         {'id': 4, 'val1': 9.3, 'val2': 19.2},
         {'id': 5, 'val1': 96.0, 'val2': 196.0},
         {'id': 6, 'val1': 99.0, 'val2': 198.0},
         {'id': 7, 'val1': 103.0, 'val2': 202.0},
         {'id': 8, 'val1': 140.0, 'val2': 280.0}]
)

def rows_in_range(row):
    index = row.name
    val1 = row['val1']
    val2 = row['val2']
    return (df['val1'].between(val1*(1-.1), val1*(1+.1)) &
            df['val2'].between(val2*(1-.1), val2*(1+.1)) &
            (df.index != index)
           )

# row.name gives the index value for that row
ids = df.apply(
    lambda row: df.loc[rows_in_range(row), 'id'].tolist(),
    axis=1,
    result_type='reduce'
)

indices
0       [2, 4]
1       [1, 4]
2    [5, 6, 7]
3       [1, 2]
4    [3, 6, 7]
5    [3, 5, 7]
6    [3, 5, 6]
7           []
dtype: object
```

Now all we have to is convert the index of this to IDs as well.

```
indices.index = df.loc[indices.index, 'id']
indices.to_dict()
{1: [2, 4],
 2: [1, 4],
 3: [5, 6, 7],
 4: [1, 2],
 5: [3, 6, 7],
 6: [3, 5, 7],
 7: [3, 5, 6],
 8: []}
```

I'm curious whether this is performant enough for millions of rows, but at least it's correct.

Comment: here the range should be calculated for val1 and val2 both and also id is one of the column not index

Comment: @ShadabHussain I updated my answer to take `val1` and `val2` both into account. My answer correctly uses `id`; it merely uses the index to find the right `id`s.

Comment: Yes logically this works fine for the smaller data frame, but when you have millions of records, performance is one of the issues. I'm looking for how we can overcome this performance issue